# ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: /home/lopa/gemeinsamerordner/movies.csv/

Tags: mysql, linux, csv, export-to-csv

Why does that not work?
Its on Ubuntu 20.04 -> mySQL

MariaDB [testdb]> select * from movies into "/home/lopa/gemeinsamerordner/movies.csv/" Fields enclosed by ',' Terminated by ';' Escaped by ',' lines Terminated by '\r\n';

I dont know what to do.

ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: /home/lopa/gemeinsamerordner/movies.csv/

Comment: Because into should be INTO OUTFILE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: Thanks it works, but i have a new problem now.

lopa@mariadb-srv:~$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 2 lopa lopa   4096 Feb  9 12:20 transfer


MariaDB [testdb]> select * from movies into outfile "/home/lopa/transfer/movies.csv" Fields enclosed by ',' Terminated by ';' Escaped by ',' lines Terminated by '\r\n';


I cant save it there, because i dont have the permission. But i changed the Modifyers of it.

ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/lopa/transfer/movies.csv' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

Comment: Search for mysql outfile permission deinied.